Accessing layer properties for expression syntax in QGIS Modeler
Overview: In QGIS I want to create a conditional branch in the model designer so that I can pass images with 20m resolution through the 'Warp (reproject)' tool. Images that are already at 10m resolution will skip this step.
Tool: Conditional Branching
Problem: To be clear, I am new to expressions in QGIS (and QGIS as a whole). I do know coding, however. It appears as though there is a selection of variables that one can choose from when creating an expression (condition) for the 'Conditional Branch' tool.

I would like to access the pixel size value, however, it appears as if this argument is not a straightforward argument to be passed. Instead, one must first access the property via the argument crs_description (if I understood correctly). However, from this point on, I am lost.

I did run raster information on the image, which is how I concluded that the 'Pixel Size' value is a crs property and not part of the metadata. How can I access this attribute from the 'crs_description' argument passed to the 'layer_property' function?

And as a final follow-up question, will the layer_property() function return the pixel value? In this case, I assume I would then need to change the function to be similar to the following:


Pixel size is connected to the CRS, since it describes the size of a pixel measured in the lenght-unit of the CRS, but a m-based CRS may have pixels of 0.10 m size or of 100 m size or even more.

I see. The pixel sizes here have a unit size of 10m or 20m, depending on the satellite band. So the layer_property() function will return the crs_description, if I pass 'crs_description' as the property parameter.
(1) Is there a way to use this in a Python IDE outside of the 'Expression Dialog' in the Model Builder, so that I can investigate further?
(2) Ultimately, I just want to access the pixel value from the returned data. Is there a way to see what attributes the returned object has, within the Expression Dialog or the Model Builder?

You can use Raster layer properties:

@Raster_layer_properties_PIXEL_HEIGHT > 15
The conditions are used as dependencies to the following tools:

If the input raster has a pixel size above 15: Extract its extent,
If below 15: Create some random points.

